# javascript function return value from mongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

Im quite new to Javascript. i have a problem and i cant figure out what is wrong with my code. i have a function that should return a value from a mongoDB database. but it seems to return as empty every time. the function sites inside a JSON object like so:

```
getRecord: function (criteria) {

    var record = {};

    cats.findOne(criteria, function (err, results) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        record = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));
    });

    return record;
},
```

i have tried console.log inside the findOne function and it is logging what i expect to be returned, but the value seems to get destroyed outside the function.

im using "record = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));" to try and create a brand new object (because i expect that the returned results from the DB would be deleting objects after the function has run).

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: so when i put the return statement in side the callback function and now it returns undefined.

Comment: put `record = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)); return record` in `else` statement